# ajax combobox not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, combobox

I am trying to use ajax combobox in my asp.net web forms.

I have added ajax toolkit and I can use other controls like PopupControlExtender etc. but when I use comboBox it gives an error saying ComboBox is not a known element.

I right-clicked on AjaxControl Toolkit in the Toolbar--> Choose Items and verified that ComboBox is checked but it doesn't appear in the ToolBar

Does anyone know what the issue may be or has faced a similar problem ?

**EDIT** :

Code :

```
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID ="ScriptManager1" />
                 Describe how spicy you like your food:
            <br />
            <cc1:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Mild" Value="0" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Medium" Value="1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Hot" Value="2" />
            </cc1:ComboBox>     

           <%-- <asp:Button
                ID="btnSubmit"
                Text="Submit"
                Runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />--%>


        </div>
```

Also,I have added this to the top of my page after the page directive :

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

Any idea,anyone ?

Comment: Can you post some code/pics and possibly help us reproduce the issue...?

Comment: eh, sorry my bad...I thought this was a noob post again...but it sure makes one look away...no offence meant...

Comment: @deostoll-None taken !

Comment: Is AjaxControlToolkit a third party and you just embed it into your app?

Comment: Yes,I guess so ! But other controls are working..only comboBox

Comment: Are you using the old version, or the updated version now maintained by DevExpress? https://www.devexpress.com/Products/AJAX-Control-Toolkit/

Comment: I used the link in Zack's answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-asp-net-ajax-control-toolkit-in-my-net-3-5-web-app

Comment: Any idea as to how should I solve this would indeed be helpful !